# How to using regex in express-unless?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to make a auth middleware in express.js and making some api's open with the help of express-unless package, in them there i added a dynamic path for ignore auth for all the urls which have 7 digit alphanumeric character. so, i added a regex `[0-9a-zA-Z]{7}` but it is not working.

below is the javascript code i wrote

```
const unprotected = ["api/token", "/", "/api/login",   /\/[0-9A-Za-z]{7}/];

module.exports.tokenAuth = jwt({...}).unless({ path: unprotected });
```

an edited code for ref:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const morganMiddleware = require("./middlewares/morganMiddleware");
const jwt = require("express-jwt");

// setting up middleware
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(morganMiddleware);


const unprotected = [ "/api/login", /\/[0-9A-Za-z]{7}/];
app.use(jwt({ secret: 'shhhhhhared-secret', algorithms: ['HS256']}).unless({ path: unprotected }));


app.get("/:id([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "unprotected",
        id: req.params.id
    })
})

app.post("/api/urlShortener", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.user)  //undefined
    res.json({
        message: "should be protected, but still works without token",
        user: req.user
    })
})

let PORT = process.env.PORT || 3333;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Application listening on port ", PORT);
  console.log("Server running on \033[0;94mhttp://localhost:" + PORT + "/ \033[0m");
});
```

can anybody help with this?

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Be sure to include them in your question.

Comment: nope, just api call responded as token required, it means regex not working

Comment: So you need to find somrthing like this: `/250Zip0`, or `/xXd290o`?

Comment: yes, but when i hit the api call it shows token required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some testing using your path and regex, and it's works. I'm not using express-unless in this case, because express-jwt already had this mechanism.

```js
const express = require("express")
const jwt = require("express-jwt")
const app = express()

const unprotected = ["api/token", "/", "/api/login",   /\/[0-9A-Za-z]{7}/];

app.use(jwt({ secret: 'shhhhhhared-secret', algorithms: ['HS256']}).unless({path: unprotected}))

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "unprotected"
    })
})

app.get("/:id([a-zA-Z0-9]{7})", (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        message: "unprotected",
        id: req.params.id
    })
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    console.log("ok")
})
```

Test case 1:

[root path localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBp5D.png)

Test case 2:

[using localhost/250Zip0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZocNo.png)

Test case 3:

[using localhost/user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm8q1.png)

**Update**

I have receive an update from TS that working regex is :

`/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/`

Example : https://regex101.com/r/TdwXNH/1

If we don't add starting string `^` but only `$` at the end. It should match all paths with this pattern regardless of the prefix.

`/^\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{7}$/`

Example 2 : https://regex101.com/r/DmkQGl/1

Comment: i just tried writing the same code, but in my case i don't know why everything became unprotected . can you help with that

Comment: got to know regex should matched the 7 digits because i haven't added ^ at the starting and $ at the end so the final regex that worked /^\/[0-9A-Za-z]{7}$/